# In Scipy, How to check for differences between 2 sparse matrices?

Tags: scipy, sparse-matrix

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46798631/difference-between-2-scipy-sparse-csr-matrices) is related and there is another [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30685024/check-if-two-scipy-sparse-csr-matrix-are-equal) dealing with equality, but if I have two sparse matrices (and they are coo format) how do I find which positions in the matrices are different?

If I were to subtract two matrices, I would still have to figure out which ones are nonzero.

I am seeing some non-deterministic values in my matrix formation, therefore I am trying to to find out which cells are changing (a smaller number) and which are consistent across runs (the overwhelming majority)

Comment: Are there differences in sparsity (the indices of the nonzero elements), or just differences in values of matching nonzero elements?  `coo` matrices can have the nonzero values in any order, which will make comparisons hard.  And math (such as subtraction) is not defined for `coo` format - they are usually converted to `csr` for that.

Comment: @hpaulj If I call find on the csr version of matrix 1 and then find on the csr version of matrix 2, it does appear that there is a difference in sparsity (that is some values in one of the matrices is zero in the other).

Answer (score 1):

[`scipy.sparse` has a built in function called `find`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.find.html#scipy.sparse.find) for determining which entries are non-zero.

Subtracting the two matricies from one another and feeding it into `scipy.sparse.find` will return all the entries which have changed (and thus were different in the original matricies).

Comment: This answer taken with @hpaulj worked for me.  First, get your coo matrices into csr format.  Then second, you are able to subtract the two matrices like C= B -A where B and A are the two matrices being compared.  Third, call find on the difference matrix and get back a 3-tuple which gives rows, columns and (nonzero) values respectively.